# update in data flow with validation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a case of updating the target table where source columns data not equal to target columns data. I am trying to do this in data flow OLE DB command component but not supporting multiple usage of the columns. I don't want to use the MERGE statement due to the database hits in this business logic.

UPDATE targettable

set column1 = @sourcecolumn1

, column2 = @sourcecolumn2

, column3 = @sourcecolumn3

WHERE column1 != @sourcecolumn1

AND column2 != @sourcecolumn2

AND column3 != @sourceclolumn3

basically, it needs to check for any changes in all the fields in the target table with source data, if any changes then update other wise no update.

Any directions on implementing this secnario in data folw.

thanks

prav

Comment: OK, after a while logical thinking on existing components I used COPY COLUMN component to make Copys' of @sourcecolumns so I have 3 original source columns and 3 copy of source columns then I can use the OLE DB Command as UPDATE VALIDATOR.

thanks

prav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at a checksum SSIS component.

It creates a checksum in the target table that is compared to the original source and can be set to pass on only those rows where changes have been made.

I've used this one in the past without any major problems: [Checksum Transformation](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Checksum-Transformation.aspx)

There is a decent tutorial for it here: [Checksum Walkthrough](http://stef-bauer.com/2010/03/19/ssis-checksum-a-must-have-skill/)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the quick reply, however as Enterprise DW implementation, client is not interested to take other than existing components. 

thanks

prav